# Migrate from Calabash(Ruby) to Appium(Java)

Tags: java, ruby, appium, calabash

We're currently using Calabash to automate mobile apps on Android and iOS. As calabash only supports ruby, entire code base is written in ruby. 
Now we want to migrate to Appium using Java bindings. Having said that, we want we reuse as much as possible. We are using cucumber for Appium so that we can reuse Feature files as is its.

Is there any tool (open source or commercial) that we can use to covert our ruby code to Java?

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite completely. There is no tool which does this.